# jqGrid - Get records before search in single field search

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

Does jqGrid just have any callback *after* single field search?

The onSearch callback fires only when the 'Search' button is clicked, so if you want to get the records of the search with `$("#grid").getGridParam('records');` you get the previous requested rows's count.

**Edit:**

This is the code where I use `onSearch`

```
onSearch:function(){
    var ofilter = $("#competitors").getGridParam("postData");
    var jqSearchQuery = "";
    $.each(ofilter, function(key, val) { jqSearchQuery += key + '=' + val + '&' ;})
    selectopts = new Array();
    selectopts['cn'] = 'contiene';
    selectopts['bw'] = 'empiece por';
    selectopts['eq'] = 'igual';
    selectopts['ne'] = 'no igual';
    selectopts['lt'] = 'menor que';
    selectopts['gt'] = 'mayor que';
    selectopts['ew'] = 'termina por';
    var records = $("#competitors").getGridParam('records');

    searchResult = records+" resultados para la b&uacute;squeda <b>\""+ofilter.searchField+" "+selectopts[ofilter.searchOper]+" "+ofilter.searchString+"\"</b>";
    $('#searchResult').html('<p>'+searchResult+'</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [onSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) callback which will be called *before* starting reloading with new filtered options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oleg, I have edited and added the code... please take a look because in this callback I get the previous queried records from the grid.

Comment: @Ezep: Sorry, but probably it's more the language problem. Do you want to display the previous requested rows or not? The `onSearch` get you the last possibility to save the count of the previous queried records. If you want to display the number of records *after applying the new filter* you should do this inside of the `loadComplete`.

Comment: Sorry! I just had a bad typo... Yes, loadComplete is what I'm looking for !